# Inserting USB with autorun.inf

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, autorun, autoplay

If i don't have autoplay on, but i still open folder to view files of that USB stick, will the autorun.inf file be executed anyway with autoplay option disabled? Does autorun.inf only gets executed from USB on computer with autoplay enabled?

Comment: you have been asking questions (new member). Please read the Help tour to understand expectations the site has for you to follow up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows 7 it is not possible any more to run `autorun.inf`
with USB flash drives anymore. Microsoft has removed this support for security reasons.

This is still available for CDs and DVDs, but not for USB sticks.

See Wikipedia
[autorun.inf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf).

Comment: Even if i have autoplay enabled?

Comment: Yes, the play verb has been suppressed and is no longer available for USB.

Answer (score 0):

> I still open folder to view files of that USB stick, will the
> autorun.inf file be executed anyway.

If autoplay is disabled, the autorun.inf file will not execute automatically.  Autoplay is mostly not available so for devices like USB it does not matter.

However, you can run any autorun file and anything else that is on the key.

Autoplay just makes things easy for any device that can use it. It does not prevent running anything at all.

So then, you need to be careful about what you are running.